# Serve Scaled Images

Tags: image, responsive-design

So I'm trying to resolve my sites bad "served scaled image" grade - see here: http://cl.ly/image/1A430t0k1r0s

I'm using a responsive site powered by Wordpress. I'm using one image on my homepage full width slider (so the image needs to be large). How can I fix this score?

url: http://cl.ly/1n162x1K3O15

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the GZip compression technique and browser caching to resolve this problem. The below is the code for simple GZip compression but you can check it out in detail [**here**](http://webdesign.about.com/od/speed/ht/website-compression.htm)

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|svg|pdf|flv|mp3)$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive on
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month 2 days 3 hours" //example you can change it
 Header set Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Go for [**adaptive images**](http://adaptive-images.com/) if this still doesn't work.

Comment: Using gzip on binary formats like images or mp3 is rather useless, because those formats already compress their data using the same or similar algorithms. (For svg/pdf this is different.) So with gzipping those you are just wasting processing time with in 99% of cases no real benefit in transfer size.

Comment: Thanks...I'm using a cache plugin...any other thoughts here.

Comment: Gzip compression did nothing for my served scaled image...still getting a D grade on the reponsive site. How do I keep the size of my image high but still get a good score?